# What are the odds of picking up 10 cards of a deck of 30 (18 red and 12 blue) and only getting 2 blue cards?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm pretty sure you use summation,

10

Σ   (equation here)

n-1

Let's say I pick up a red one. I already know to calculate the odds of getting one (18/30=.6=60%) but what I am asking is what the odds are of picking up *multiple* cards of different variety.

but what do you do about the 2 blue cards? Do you just replace 10 with 8 since you only got 2 blue cards, or is there something else you have to do?

Edit: I am asking what are the odds of drawing *exactly* 2 blue cards, not at least 2 blue cards

Edit 2:
This is a good example of what I want to do, but I don't understand the math part of it

Suppose there are 5 black, 10 white, and 15 red marbles in an urn. If six marbles are chosen without replacement, the probability that exactly two of each color are chosen is

https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/d1c732a6291d8d06d36d382de45c024b1b769a4a

Comment: Do you mean *exactly* two blue cards or *at most* two blue cards?  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  Please address those questions in the question itself rather than the comments where they might be missed.

Comment: The deck has 30 total cards, 18 red, and 12 blue. What are the odds that I pick up 10 cards, 2 of which are blue ones. Doesn't matter which order they come in.

Comment: To get exactly two blue cards when selecting $10$ of the $30$ cards from the deck, you must choose two of the $12$ blue cards and eight of the $18$ red cards.  This is a [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) problem.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to figure it out now. I don't totally understand it yet, but if I do, I will update the thread.

Comment: The example you cited is very similar to this problem.  Only here, you only have two colors of cards to worry about.

Comment: Alright, the answer is 0.948444 thanks for your help!

Comment: The probability you found is not correct.  I posted an answer, which I hope you will find helpful.

Comment: I did 2888028/3045015 instead of 2888028/30045015 my bad. Didn't type the second zero in the front

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We wish to find the probability of obtaining exactly two blue cards when selecting $10$ of the $30$ cards from the deck.  For this to happen, we must select $2$ of the $12$ blue cards and $8$ of the $18$ red cards.  This event has probability
$$\frac{\dbinom{12}{2}\dbinom{18}{8}}{\dbinom{30}{10}}$$
This is an example of a [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) problem since the cards are selected without replacement.

The number
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$
(read $n$ choose $k$) represents the number of ways of selecting a subset of $k$ objects from a set with $n$ objects.  See this page on [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Comment: After seeing the equation everything clicked. Thank you!